# My Canon MG3620 is seen, by Ubuntu Studio, as paused

Tags: drivers, printing, android, canon

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04LTS on my newer laptop and 12.04LTS on the older one.

I was able to use my Canon MG3620 from both without any problems until yesterday, when both laptops started reporting status messages that kept them from using the printer.

I am able to print to it from my android phone without a problem, but now, both laptops are seeing a status message that the printer is paused.

Since the printer works from the android phone, I cannot see the printer being the problem.

So, how do I go about clearing those status messages from the laptops?

I'd rather not reinstall the drivers if I don't have to.